# sql2o with SQLite in Java NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, sqlite, sql2o

I've got the following code snippet so far:

```
Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");

try (Connection connection = sql2o.open()) {
    for (Column column : connection.createQuery("SELECT * FROM sometable").executeAndFetchTable().columns())
        System.out.println(column.toString());
}
```

I'm using these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sql2o</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql2o</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, this throws a NoInitialContextException when executing. Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at org.sql2o.JndiDataSource.getJndiDatasource(JndiDataSource.java:27)
        at org.sql2o.Sql2o.<init>(Sql2o.java:36)
        at me.mypackage.sqlitetest.SqliteTest.main(SqliteTest.java:11)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at org.sql2o.JndiDataSource.getJndiDatasource(JndiDataSource.java:24)
        ... 2 more
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing this line

```
Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
```

with

```
Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o("jdbc:sqlite:test.db", null, null);
```

The [`Sql2o`](http://api.sql2o.org/org/sql2o/sql2o) class has a constructor which takes only a single string, however that single string is a JNDI name, not a JDBC connection URL. There is another constructor that takes three strings, for the connection URL, username and password.   SQLite doesn't use the username and password, so we can specify `null` values for them both.

Comment: Thanks! I must've omitted that from the MySQL example because I thought it'd work without credentials since there's no need for that... damn.